# IIS Configuration

Tags: iis, asp.net, iis-8

I've enabled IIS using "Add/Remote Windows Features" and I'm trying to run some ASP.NET code from localhost. I've not done anything else to configure it. Is there any additional configuration I need to do in order to be able to test locally?

I'm running Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting my code to run by installing [Abyss Web Server](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/). It was far easier to set up for this sort of thing than IIS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure you've enabled ASP.NET from within "Add/Remove Windows Features" as well.   Under the IIS tree, you need to enable WWW Services -> ASP.NET

Once ASP.NET has been installed, if you're using Visual Studio it can configure IIS for you.  You'll need to run VS as Administrator, then open your project.  Open the web project properties and select the "Web" tab.  From there you'll want to choose "Use Local IIS Web server" and setup the url you'd like to use.

Here is a screenshot of how to get to the project properties.  In this image "MVC5Demo" is a web application project:

[image: Web Project Properties]

Comment: Where do I find the web project properties?

Comment: Right click on the web project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties"

Comment: What do you mean by web project? I'm right clicking on the solution but I don't see a window like you describe (as in, no Web tab).

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Are you sure your project is a Web Application project?  Also what version of VS are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012. It's a WebSite, having nothing to do with MVC (as your screenshot implies).

Comment: You can't run ASP.NET code from a website project.  You need to use one of the ASP.NET application projects.

Comment: I've seen it run on Windows Server, though. I just wanted to test it locally to avoid having to move it over to the server every time.
 I'm just looking to run the `.aspx` files. This isn't possible?